# How to create a list of lists from a string?

Tags: python, string, list

I read from stdin the following type of strings in Python:

```
"[['A', '0', '12.0'], ['A', '1', '10.0'], ['B', '1', '10.0']]"
```

How can I turn them into a list of lists?

Comment: That is a list of lists!

Comment: Congratulations, you did it already.

Comment: My bad. I changed the post. Those are strings that I read and I want to turn them into lists of lists

Comment: ...that's still a list of lists of strings. Please give a [mcve] that actually reflects the problem you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 7):

If you mean you have that in a string, use `ast.literal_eval()`:

```
>>> s = "[['A', '0', '12.0'], ['A', '1', '10.0'], ['B', '1', '10.0']]"
>>> import ast
>>> ast.literal_eval(s)
[['A', '0', '12.0'], ['A', '1', '10.0'], ['B', '1', '10.0']]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
new_list = eval("[['A', '0', '12.0'], ['A', '1', '10.0'], ['B', '1', '10.0']]")
```